# Android : how to check programmatically, if your smartphone has a mono or stereo output (1 or 2 speakers)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am implementing a multimedia player and I need to understand when opening my application if the smartphone on which it is installed has a mono or stereo output (1 or 2 speakers).
Thanks

Comment: Can you please share what have you researched till now?

Comment: AudioManager, Mediaplayer and AudioDeviceInfo. They have no functionality for obtaining this information.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at [this official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#summary), is about audio manager.